# Is AD7794 a good alternative to Hx711 for multi-channel ADC?

Tags: voltage-regulator, adc, instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell

**note: Electronics isn't my main background so I might make silly mistakes. I did read the datasheet but don't understand all the terms despite my effort. Suggestions are welcome.**

AD7794 ([datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7794_7795.pdf)) is 6 channel 24 bit ADC with on-chip gain of 128.

**Questions:**

1. My load cell outputs `+-20mV at FS` so `128 gain = 2.56V` which is suitable for ADC. But does in-amp has minimum voltage that it can amplify?
2. Is this chip also able to take `-20mV input`?
3. The `AVDD = 2.7V to 5.25V`. So as long as I supply voltage within that range, will I be okay?
4. If I look at `INA125` instrumentation amplifier([datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina125.pdf)), it has voltage regulator of 10V, 5V and so on. I can supply load cell with the regulated voltage and amplify the output in mV. But I don't seem to find such feature in `AD7794`. However there is 1.17V reference which I don't know what it is used for. So do I need to add separate voltage reference for excitation?
5. Am I overlooking anything if I intend to use this for load cell?

BTW, if you know other ADC with multi-channel ADC, I am open for it also.

Edit: There is also available breakout board at [tindie](https://www.tindie.com/products/jtinker/6-ch-24-bit-full-bridge-sensor-featherwing/). I don't know if there is any issue with arduino or not. But I hope not.

Regards,

Comment: What load cell are you using? Note that the AD7794 is a *very* complex device and the entire signal chain needs to be evaluated.

Comment: @PeterSmith I am using a generic one. I do need to take readings from multiple ones so I need multi-channel one.

Can you explain me more about ' entire signal chain needs to be evaluated'?

Comment: The input common mode range of the AD7794 varies depending on how it is configured; if your load cell can output a value in the middle of it's power rails (swinging around Vcc/2 for instance) then it may be a good candidate.

Comment: @PeterSmith Load cell generates `±20mV`. 

Newbie here and I don't understand the datasheet fully nor the terms. 

In instrumentation section, it mentions -> with external 2.5V reference, unipolar ranges are 0-20mV to 0-2.5V and bipolar ranges are ±20mV to ±2.5V. But it also warns that in bipolar configuration, it can't tolerate -ve voltages wrt ground. pg-31.